# I have three input fields. When one has any information in it, the others should be disabled. Can I express this more succinctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var ContentEditingHelper;
$(ContentEditingHelper = function () {
    var costCenterSelector = '#CostCenter';
    var projectSubcodeSelector = '#ProjectSubcode';
    var incidentNumberSelector = '#IncidentNumber';

    //This bit of code affects the 'Add New Order' dialog. It works on the 'Incident Number', 'Project Subcode', and 'Cost Center' input fields.
    //Since only one of these fields is allowed to be populated at a time -- use jQuery to disable the other fields when typing is detected in one.
    $(this).on('keyup', '#CostCenter, #ProjectSubcode, #IncidentNumber', function () {
        if ($(this).val() === '') {
            $(costCenterSelector).prop('disabled', false);
            $(projectSubcodeSelector).prop('disabled', false);
            $(incidentNumberSelector).prop('disabled', false);
        }
        else {
            switch (this.id) {
                case 'CostCenter':
                    $(projectSubcodeSelector).prop('disabled', true);
                    $(incidentNumberSelector).prop('disabled', true);
                    break;
                case 'ProjectSubcode':
                    $(costCenterSelector).prop('disabled', true);
                    $(incidentNumberSelector).prop('disabled', true);
                    break;
                case 'IncidentNumber':
                    $(costCenterSelector).prop('disabled', true);
                    $(projectSubcodeSelector).prop('disabled', true);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    //Public methods go here.
    return {
    };
} ());
```

So I've got this and it works. There are some clear code smells and some not-so-clear. I would like to be able to be able to reuse my selector names as much as possible. Is it possible to use them in my declaration of on? And how should I handle my case statements?

Furthermore, is there an overall easier way to achieve my goal?

Comment: I *really* don't understand the `var ContentEditingHelper; $(ContentEditingHelper = function () {` purpose. `var ContentEditingHelper = function () { ... }; $(ContentEditingHelper);` OR `function ContentEditingHelper () { ... }; $(ContentEditingHelper);` will do *almost* the same thing, but neater.

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you mean from code in a comment, but my intention was to expose a ContentEditingHelper object globally (I intend for it to have public methods in the future) while not leaking private  code outside of its scope. Feel free to post a pastebin/gist of what you're describing and we can discuss.

Comment: Ok to do that simple, in your code: You declare `ContentEditingHelper` globally, you auto-execute a function, you assign the undefined result to `ContentEditingHelper` and then you pass that to the fancy "jQuery documentReady"... it's like doing `var ContentEditingHelper = (function() { }()); $(document).ready(undefined)`

Comment: Won't that execute the anonymous function before document ready, though? The code I currently have assigns to ContentEditingHelper after document ready.

Comment: Your function is executed before the dom is ready because you tell it to. Look at what is between `$()` -» `ContentEditingHelper = function() { ... }()` so it execute itself, and THEN it is passed to `$()`. What you putted in `$()`is an expression. It will execute the expression, and then pass the result of this expression to `$()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $inputs = $('#CostCenter, #ProjectSubcode, #IncidentNumber');

$inputs.on('keyup', function() {
    $inputs.not(this).prop('disabled', this.value !== '');
});
```

---

If your elements are not available at document ready, use this:

```
var selector = '#CostCenter, #ProjectSubcode, #IncidentNumber';

$(document).on('keyup', selector, function() {
    $(selector).not(this).prop('disabled', this.value !== '');
});
```

Just keep in mind that this will query the DOM on *every single `keyup`*!! Are you sure you can't somehow do this differently?

Comment: This works slightly differently than my code. The inputs do not exist at the time the code is ran. Your code will only bind to elements which already exist in the DOM tree, but I do see where you are going with it.

Comment: @SeanAnderson - Just added a code snippet for that too.

Comment: Thanks. That helped. jQuery is better at working with collections of selectors than I thought :o

Comment: The `not(this)` won't work, since it refers to `document`. Use `$(e.target)`.

Comment: Huh? It works fine. this changes scope inside of the function to reference the element firing the keyup event.

Comment: I meant in the second solution when he uses `$(document).on`.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine - [Why would you say that](http://jsfiddle.net/BzYzL/)?

Comment: Oh, my. jQuery does way too much magic for me to remember everything. My bad!

Comment: I'm not crazy, jQuery does the magic: http://jsfiddle.net/55fvA/2/

Comment: @FlorianMargaine - That's just event bubbling. jQuery is doing event delegation...

Comment: A user can also change an input's value with the context menu and drag-and-drop, neither of which fire `keyup`. `input` catches everything (and, as a bonus, doesn't fire for non-changing keystrokes like arrow keys), but isn't compatible with IE<9.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ContentEditingHelper = {};

// Apply the right class there.
$(document).on('keyup', '.inputs', function (e) {

    // First, disable all the fields.
    $('.inputs').prop('disabled', true);

    // Then, enable the one that was clicked.
    $(e.target).prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Also, there is no need to declare this in your `ContentEditingHelper`. I didn't surround the jQuery code by an IIFE because there is no variable declared, but you could just use this if necessary:

```
(function() {
    $(document).on...
}());
```

Only put in the `ContentEditingHelper` object what's needed. This is commonly called a namespace by the way.